# Implementing a return navigation in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am looking for a JSF coding practice that will allow one page to link to another that, when it completes, will return to the original page.  So I have a page **viewDoc.xhtml** that has this:

```
        <f:metadata>
                <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{viewDoc.id}" />
        </f:metadata>

        ( bunch of stuff to show the document indicated by "id" )

        <p:button value="Edit Name/Title"
              outcome="editnametitle">
                <f:param name="id" value="#{param.id}" />
        </p:button>
```

Then I have a page **editnametitle.xhtml** that has this:

```
  <h:form>
     (input fields and stuff)
                <p:commandButton value="Save Changes"
                                 action="#{editNameTitle.doSave()}"
                                 />

                <p:commandButton value="Cancel"
                                 action="#{editNameTitle.doCancel()}"
                                 immediate="true"
                                 />
  </h:form>
```

So how do I implement the backing bean methods **doSave()** and **doCancel()** such that when they finish they navigate back to **viewDoc.xhtml** with the **id** parameter of the document included?

I haven't found any guidance for a solution and I haven't been happy with any approach I have thought of so far.   I have thought of something like adding to the **p:button** the return path like:

```
<p:button value="Edit Name/Title"
      outcome="editnametitle">
      <f:param name="id" value="#{param.id}" />
      <f:param name="returnoutcome" value="viewDoc" />
</p:button>
```

Is this the right approach?  Or is there some JSF facility that does this that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's basically it if those requests are idempotent.

One possible improvement is that you can dynamically obtain the current view ID as below:

```
<f:param name="returnoutcome" value="#{view.viewId}" />
```

This allows abstracting away it in a reusable custom tag.
Personally I'd use parameter name "from" too as that's more short.